# OnCollision or OnTrigger issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on the "2D Vehicle Kit" you can see it asset store easily (its free).

It has 2D car and moves on a Built terrain. I want to add coins on it and add score when the car hits coin.

But i can not get the collision between two of them. Car object is totally using 2D rigid body and other 2D things.

I tried using OnCollision or OnTrigger but didn't worked.

Some one please help me to get to collision.

Link to same question: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/oncollision-or-ontrigger-issues.266729/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write an implementation of [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) unless you have set your colliders as triggers, in which case you need to use [OnTriggerEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)